# Fetch projects not in group from GitLab

Tags: api, gitlab

I'm currently trying to fetch a list of projects from the GitLab API by pinging this endpoint `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?min_access_level=40&page=1&per_page=25. It seems that this returns a list of projects including the ones in groups that I own. Is there a way I can limit my search to only projects that are not in groups?